# ABP: Rebuilding Localization Sources from Custom Provider

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I am using ABP v4.9.0 (.NET CORE 2.2) with angular client

I built some custom localization providers. These providers get translation dictionaries from an external API.
I add localization sources on startup with these providers.

```
            var customProvider = new CustomLocalizationProvider(...);


            var localizationSource = new DictionaryBasedLocalizationSource("SOURCENAME", customProvider );
            config.Localization.Sources.Add(localizationSource );
```

On startup, the providers InitializeDictionaries() is called and localization dictionaries are built.
So far, so good, working as intended.

**Now i'd like to manually Reload these translations on demand, but I can't make this working.**

Here is what I tried.

Here I trigger the re-synchronize of the language ressources:

```
        foreach (var localizationSource in _localizationConfiguration.Sources)
        {
            try
            {
                localizationSource.Initialize(_localizationConfiguration, _iocResolver);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.Warn($"Could not get Localization Data for source '{localizationSource.Name}'", e);
            }
        }
```

In the custom provider, I first clear the Dictionaries

```
    public class CustomLocalizationProvider : LocalizationDictionaryProviderBase
    {

    protected int IterationNo = 0;

    protected override void InitializeDictionaries()
    {
        Dictionaries.Clear();

        IterationNo += 1;

        var deDict = new LocalizationDictionary(new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
        deDict["HelloWorld"] = $"Hallo Welt Nummer {IterationNo}";
        Dictionaries.Add("de-DE", deDict);

        var enDict = new LocalizationDictionary(new CultureInfo("en"));
        enDict["HelloWorld"] = $"Hello World number {IterationNo}";
        Dictionaries.Add("en", enDict);
    }

    }
```

The provider is executed again as expected.

But when I eventually use the localization clientside (angular), **I still get the original translations.**

What am I missing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to refresh on client side (Angular) too.

Comment: I surely did refresh the client. The old translations seem to be cached server side, not just client side

Comment: Correction: I use ABP 4.9.0 (CORE 2.2)

Comment: What is `language.LanguageCode`? You are right that the source and provider are cached, but `DictionaryBasedLocalizationSource.GetAllStrings` appears to use the latest `Dictionaries`: [DictionaryBasedLocalizationSource.cs#L141](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/v5.1.0/src/Abp/Localization/Dictionaries/DictionaryBasedLocalizationSource.cs#L141)

Comment: language.Language is an excerpt from a much longer code using data from some external service.

Comment: To help you understand and make sure the issue is not the external service, I replaced the code above by a dummy implementation of InitializeDictionaries(); - The result of the localization is always "Hallo Welt Nummer 1" in the client

Comment: @aaron: `DictionaryBasedLocalizationSource.GetAllStrings` returns the original, cached sources as well.

Comment: It does not: [acjh/aspnetboilerplate@0f6795e](https://github.com/acjh/aspnetboilerplate/commit/0f6795e92bf79a4508aeec7e54f2ef20e12b7419). Can you write a unit test that reproduces that?

Comment: Thanks for the efforts @aaron. No, I don't know how to reproduce this exact scenario. 1.) It's not 'sequential' as  in your unit-test. -  2.) I never get to execute CustomLocalizationProvider.InitializeDictionaries() explicitely; it is done internally by abp and the localizationsource (?)  - 3.) I'm not in control, which explicite instance of LocalizationSource i'm using at some other appservice. It is injected. The injected instance has the old values in it. 4.) Furthermore and foremost: I'm not in control, how the localizationsource is provided to the client (nor do I understand it TBH...)

Comment: Also tried with `localizationSource.Initialize` as you show in the question: [acjh/aspnetboilerplate@6fe5ca7](https://github.com/acjh/aspnetboilerplate/commit/6fe5ca7d0cf6a65d5bef73a3840b2a37f6ddc91f)

Comment: Cool, thank you. Still does not solve my issue. Client uses the original translations.

Comment: Can you share a project that reproduces that?

Comment: I took the latest abp template and inserted the demo-code. I flagged my changes with the keyword @Puur - testcase: click 'Reload' & reload page. expected result: 'Hello World 2' https://www.mediafire.com/file/6sw61614cllsh5c/LocalizationDemo2.zip/file

Comment: Please upload it to GitHub with your changes in a separate commit. Even better if you can fork [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).

Comment: There you go: https://github.com/osoDev/module-zero-core-template/commits/v4.x

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish this too with custom loaded dictionaries that I can manipulate at run-time. I believe you are barking at the wrong tree... But at the same time I can't get the right tree in sight elsewhere in the app. :S I believe you should somehow reach `Configuration.Localization.Sources`; then remove it and re-add a new instance (to ensure it initializes correctly; or at least in my case, this is what I would need). In your repo, the code is in `aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core/Localization/AbpProjectNameLocalizationConfigurer.cs#L12-L19`. (...)

Comment: That code is called from `aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core/AbpProjectNameCoreModule.cs#L27` (module's `PreInitialize()`). I suspect if you re-add this localization source somehow, it should update for the remaining queries. But I just can't get into this `Configuration.Localization.Sources` from outside the module. :/

Comment: 4 hours fighting it and I could make it work in an approach very similar to yours. it seems the only difference is that I also assign `DefaultDictionary = enDict;`. Could it be you're querying the default dictionary and you didn't replace it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile I had to go for another approach.

I am now using a `XmlEmbeddedFileLocalizationDictionaryProvider` wrapped by a `MultiTenantLocalizationDictionaryProvider`.
This way, I am using db-localizations with xml-sources as fallback

Then I manually load the ressources from my API in some appservice. These localizations are then updated in the database by using `LanguageTextManager.UpdateStringAsync()`.